# MySQL-ordering partitions randomly

Tags: mysql, sql, select

`table1` has 3 columns in my database: `id`, `category`, `timestamp`. I need to query the newest 3 rows from each category:

```
WITH ranked_rows AS
(SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC) AS rn
FROM table1 AS t)
SELECT ranked_rows.* FROM ranked_rows WHERE rn<=3
```

now I need to select 10 partitions from the results randomly (please notice that each partition has 3 rows). how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are various methods.  One is:

```
WITH ranked_rows AS (
      SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC) AS seqnum,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MD5(category)) as catnum
      FROM table1 t
     )
SELECT ranked_rows.*
FROM ranked_rows
WHERE seqnum <= 3 AND catnum <= 10;
```

The `md5()` just makes the results look random.

Comment: many thanks! but every time I run this query the catnum value for each partition does not change and so the result is constant.

Comment: @Soheil . . . That could be a feature, but you can just salt the `md5()`:  `md5(concat(category, now())`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want true random per category, here is one way :

```
with categorycte as (
  select category , rand() randomcatid
  from table1
  group by category
),ranked_rows AS
(
  SELECT t.*
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY t.timestamp DESC) AS rn
  , dense_rank() over (order by randomcatid) catnum
FROM table1 AS t
join categorycte c on t.category = c.category
)
SELECT ranked_rows.* FROM ranked_rows 
WHERE rn<=3 and catnum <= 10;
```